# c# calculating directory size

Tags: c#, windows-10, console-application

C# noob here, I'm trying to conduct an application to calculate the size of directories. Using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-iterate-through-a-directory-tree) as an example, I created bellow method to do so:

```
public static long CalculateSize(DirectoryInfo dir, string search = "*.*")
{
    long result = 0;
    FileInfo[] files = null;
    DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;
    try
    {
        files = dir.GetFiles(search, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    }

    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        //catch unauthorized exception
    }

    catch (PathTooLongException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PATH: " + e.Message);
    }

    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            result += file.Length;                    
        }

        subDirs = dir.GetDirectories(search, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (var directory in subDirs)
        {
            result += CalculateSize(directory, search);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Although when I run this with:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\");
var size = FileSystem.CalculateSize(dir);
Console.WriteLine(size);
```

I get nearly double the size, File Explorer shows me:
my result -> 33189002865
file explorer properties -> 12263901898
I tested this, replacing "result += file.Length" with "result++" to get the number of files the method iterates over and got large difference there as well:
my result -> 94476
file expl -> 59318

When I test this on my other drive (D:) I get absolutely the same result as File Explorer, regardless if I run this on my root, some folder inside, etc. But whenever I test on my system drive (C:) - get this strange results. I have no idea what I am doing wrong and would be thankful for your assistance!

P.S. I run my tests on Windows 10 Pro 64bit, if that's relevant.

Comment: Have you tried narrowing it down to a specific user directory, for example? My guess is that it may well be due to symbolic links or something similar, but I'd definitely focus on reproducing this with as small a set of files as possible, by looking at one subdirectory at a time.

Comment: Maybe the 'Libraries' are procesed twice, once as such and once as the underlying folders..

Comment: @JonSkeet when I run it on smaller directories - it produces perfect results. But symbolic links is a good idea to check, thank you!

Comment: @JonSkeet using `FileInfo .Lenght` wont solve the problem?

Comment: @styx: The OP is already using the `Length` property. It's not clear what change you're suggesting.

Comment: I'm starting to see a pattern. Whenever I hit UnauthorizedAccessException or PathTooLongException - it seems the method returns incorrect results. But honestly I fail to see the logic to do so, since these files are getting skipped, what could be the reason to produce larger amounts of files, than the existing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem with **File explorer**  algorithm of sizing or permissions to some specifics folders.

File explorer for path:

```
C:\Users\All Users
```

Won't show any informations like size.

So if you will check this path:

```
C:\Users\
```

It won't count size of **"C:\Users\All Users"** . But your script will count size of it.

Better windows tool for getting size of folders is DIR in cmd.

Open your cmd, and write this:

```
cd Users
dir /s /a
```

**/s** - shows all the files and folders in the specified directory

**/a** - shows all types of files and folders

(Sorry for Polish language)

Picture of good calculations for C:\Users\ (Your program and **dir /s /a**):

[image: Picture of good calculations]

What shows file explorer for C:\Users\ :

[image: What shows file explorer]

Comment: So... the whole time my method was working correctly, and File Explorer wasn't?! I've spend days trying to figure this out :O I honestly thought it might be issue with it, but who was I to judge the mighty Windows...

Comment: Check size of folder in cmd with dir /s /a, to be sure :)

Comment: Now it makes sense. Before, the result of my app showed larger sizes for several directories. Now things are starting to make sense. The differences are from files, that can't be accessed due to Unauthorized and PathTooLong exceptions.
[links](http://oi67.tinypic.com/2yza8m0.jpg). Thanks again!